# Can my profiler that is compiled with .NET 4.5 attach to a .NET 3.5 application?

Tags: c#, .net, profiling, .net-framework-version

We have a custom-written profiler that uses COR_PROFILER to attach to .NET applications. It used to be compiled with .NET 3.5 (same as the applications it profiled), but I'm thinking of compiling it with .NET 4.5 now.

If I would make that switch, would the new profiler binary still be able to profile applications that were compiled with the .NET 3.5 framework?

My initial experiments failed, so now I'm unsure if it's an issue with my setup or if it's technically not possible.

---

To be more precise: I'm compiling this C++ profiler with VS2013 and PlatformTools v120. I used to compile it with VS2010 and PlatformTools v100. v100 could profile both the 3.5 and 4.0 assemblies, v120 only profiles 4.0 assemblies.

Comment: Usually profilers are backward compatible. Profiler targeting .NET 4.5 should work with .NET 3.5. Try searching for exact error or look up at the vendor website - it something that should be published. For example, [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/features/) supports: *" variety of .NET applications, including those based on .NET Framework 2.x to 4.5, and Silverlight 4 and 5."*

Comment: are you sure there's no special handling required? My profiler works great if I compile a sample app with target framework 4.0 or 4.5, but with target framework 3.5 it does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that having my profiler implement the ICorProfiler3 interface (introduced in .NET 4) means that it can no longer profile assemblies older than .NET 4 (which, now that I write it, sounds incredibly logical... :P).

According to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd778910%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), using the old ICorProfiler2 interface means you can profile both the old and the new assemblies, but you need to set a special environment variable to cause .NET 4 to still accept that profiler.